# Jquery Dropdown not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script to generate a horizontal drop down menu on a site. It works wonderfully in Firefox and Safari, but fails in IE8 (surprise surprise). The intended behavior is that when a main menu item with a submenu is hovered over in the navigation list, the corresponding submenu will appear and any existing submenus in the .submenu div will disappear. In IE8, though, only one of the menu items will display its corresponding submenu (and then only after the link to the left of it, a link without a submenu, has been hovered), and its doing so disables the CSS hover effect on the links. [Here's](http://www.qualprnt.com/clients/fbcw/) a live example.

I'm not experienced enough in jQuery to know why I might be running into issues, so I'm asking the good folks at StackOverflow for help. Thanks!

(Edit: I'm also running ie7.js on this particular page-- I don't know if that will effect anything or not, but I thought it would be worth mentioning)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.submenu ul').hide(); //hide all submenus
                var msec = document.location.href; //get current  url
                var mshref = msec.split("/"); //trim URL to include only current section
                $('.submenu ul[class~='+mshref[3]+']').show(); //show submenu belonginging to current section

            $('.topmenu a').hover(function(){
                var msection = $(this).attr("href");
                var msechref = msection.split("/");
                if($('.submenu ul[class~='+msechref[3]+']').length){ //if there's a submenu belonging to this section
                    $('.submenu ul').hide();//hide all submenus
                    $('.submenu ul[class~='+msechref[3]+']').show(); //show the submenu for the section being hovered over
                } 
                else
                {
                $('.submenu ul').hide();//hide all submenus
                $('.submenu ul[class~='+mshref[3]+']').show();//show submenu for current section
                }

            });
        });
```

And here's the HTML.

```
        <nav><!-- top nav -->
    <div class="topmenu">
        <ul class="section_list">
<li><a class="active" href="http://test/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/about/">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/ministries/">ministries</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/news/">news</a></li>

<li><a href="http://test/sermons/">sermons</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/contact/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>      
    <div class="submenu">
        <ul class="category_list about">
<li><a href="http://test/about/?c=join-us">join us</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/about/?c=our-beliefs">our beliefs</a></li>

<li><a href="http://test/about/?c=our-staff">our staff</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/about/?c=services">services</a></li>
</ul>
        <ul class="category_list ministries">
<li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=adults">adults</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=children">children</a></li>
<li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=preschool">preschool</a></li>

<li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=youth">youth</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</nav><!-- end of top nav -->
```

Comment: Can we see some of your HTML content?

Comment: @kara I added it to the question.

Comment: Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/7Mz8j/) with IE8. If it works then there is another problem with your script and you have to show more of your code or a sample page.

Comment: @kara here's a [link](http://www.qualprnt.com/clients/fbcw/) to a live sample.

Comment: in IE8 in compatibility mode it works :) (your sample page)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I forced compatibility on the local test site and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I run some local tests and I can say it's not entirely script related. You can see it [yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/FRGft/). It works fine on IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. I want to help but it's time consuming and I can't help anymore. I hope you can find a solution.

Comment: @Kara I did. I just forced the site to run in compatibility mode in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Can you try this instead of yours:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var root = 'http://www.qualprnt.com/clients/fbcw/', $submenu = $('.submenu ul');
  $submenu.hide();
  var current = location.href.replace(root, '').split('/')[0];
  if(current != '') {
    $submenu.filter('.' + current).show();
  }
  $('.topmenu a').mouseenter(function(){
    var section = this.href.replace(root, '').split('/')[0];
    $submenu.hide();
    if(section != '') {
      $submenu.filter('.' + section).show();
    }
    else {
      if(current != '') {
        $submenu.filter('.' + current).show();
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

With this solution, you have to change `root` variable after you move the site to it's original domain. Please let me know if it works.

I will not delete my old answer, maybe it'll be useful for someone else.

**OLD ANSWER:**

If you're willing to change your CSS and HTML a little then [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/7Mz8j/3/) might be better for you.

HTML:

```
<nav><!-- top nav -->
    <div class="topmenu">
        <ul class="section_list">
            <li><a class="active" href="http://test/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://test/about/">About</a>
                <ul class="category_list">
                    <li><a href="http://test/about/?c=join-us">join us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/about/?c=our-beliefs">our beliefs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/about/?c=our-staff">our staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/about/?c=services">services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://test/ministries/">ministries</a>
                <ul class="category_list">
                    <li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=adults">adults</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=children">children</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=preschool">preschool</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://test/ministries/?c=youth">youth</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://test/news/">news</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://test/sermons/">sermons</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://test/contact/">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</nav><!-- end of top nav -->
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section_list > li').hover(
        function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.has('ul')) {
                $this.find('ul').show();
            }
        },
        function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.has('ul')) {
                $this.find('ul').hide();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I'm generating all of the navigation through a CMS, and the native tags don't allow me to use the UL > LI > UL structure. I'd have to hand-code all of the navigation items, which I'd rather not do as the client will be maintaining this going forward and I want to do as little maintenance as possible in the future.

Comment: I tried your new code, but it actually disabled the appearance of the submenus in Firefox. In a comment on the original post Mark suggested that my code worked in IE8 compatibility mode; I forced compatibility mode on the localhost test site and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

change your script tags:

```
<script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Didn't have any effect sadly. Though your previous suggestion of viewing the site in compatibility mode DID work. I'll try Kara's suggestion below, but if I still can't get it working I'll have to force compatibility in IE8.

Comment: There are some other script tags other than the three plain ones with src= but no type as well (jquery min one for example).  Nothing giving an "error" but bad behavior I have observed before when type is omitted OR if the script tag is made self closing.

Comment: no type here either: `<script src='http://www.qualprnt.com/clients/fbcw/js/jquery.googlecalreader-1.0.js'></script>
`